# Saving in one shot two parents and one child Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have never had a case where I want to save multiple parents and  one child in one shot. In my case, I have two parent entities and one child. The two parent entities have a foreign key on the child entity.

I have an example like this ->

```
@Entity
@Table("parentA")
public class ParentA
{
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long ID; 

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parentA")
private List<Child> child;

// Getters and Setters and some methods
}



@Entity
@Table("ParentB")
public class ParentB
{

@Column("CODE")
private Long code;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parentB")
private List<Child> child;

// Getters and Setters and some methods}

@Entity
@Table("Child")
public class Child
{  
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column("ID")
private Long ID;

@Column("parentA_ID")
private Long parentAId;

@Column("code")
private String code;//from parentB

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "parentA_ID")
private ParentA parentA;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "code", referencedColumnName = "code")
private ParentB parentB;
// Getters and Setters and some methods}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You probably want to save your child and expect parentA and parentB also to be persisted? In that case turn on the needed cascade types of parentA and parentB.

Comment: I want to save all of them in one shot. The parent entities and the child entity. Doesn't  the CascadeType.ALL includes the persistent and merge type ?

Comment: I get error `Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.jpa.Child column: id` for your entities. You declare three `id` columns in your `Child` entity, which is incorrect. What was your intention? By the way, declaring `referencedColumnName` is not needed for this case.

Comment: Can you also clarify using an example which all entities you want to save.

Comment: @AlexeyVeleshko I have modified the code a bit. I want to save all three entites. I can multiple child records(CHILD) and lets say one record for each parent(PARENTA and PARENTB) that I want to save in the corresponding tables.  The code I provided is just an example. But if you have another one better to show me the solution of my problem that would be awesome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add attribute `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` to `Child` fields:

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn
    private ParentA parentA;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn
    private ParentB parentB;

    // ...
}

public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Integer> {
}
```

Then the parent entities will be saved when you save the child entity:

```
ChildRepository childRepo;

// ...

    var child = new Child();
    var parentA = new ParentA();
    var parentB = new ParentB();

    parentA.setChild(List.of(child));
    parentB.setChild(List.of(child));
    child.setParentA(parentA);
    child.setParentB(parentB);

    childRepo.save(child);
```

You can see that a single `save` inserted all three rows:

```
DEBUG n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener - 
Name:dataSource, Connection:4, Time:52, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["insert into parenta values ( )"]
Params:[()]
DEBUG n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener - 
Name:dataSource, Connection:4, Time:0, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["insert into parentb values ( )"]
Params:[()]
DEBUG n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener - 
Name:dataSource, Connection:4, Time:0, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["insert into child (parenta_id, parentb_id) values (?, ?)"]
Params:[(3,3)]
```